# Links in natural text VS plain list format

Tags: seo

Our home page features links to our 4 main sub pages (it's really more, but I'll use 4 as an example). It's currently just a list of links in the content body:

> - [Custom websites designed for desktop, tablets, and mobile phones](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#)
> - [Domain Name Registration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#)
> - [Website Hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#)
> - [Ecommerce Solutions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#)

Disregarding user experience for better or worse and focusing on SEO only, I considered working the links into a paragraph in a more organic way:

> We create [custom websites designed for desktop, tablets, and mobile phones](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#). We take care of everything from [domain name registration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#), [website hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#), [ecommerce solutions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/links-in-natural-text-vs-plain-list-format#) and more!

My assumption is that the paragraph form is preferred because it is more natural and reads better. From an SEO perspective, is there much of a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that surrounds links is a ranking factor for the page receiving the link. How much is unknown but it does matter. In this case there isn't a whole lot of text surrounding the links in the paragraph so I don't think it is going to make much of a difference either way.

Just go with whatever is better for the user (and/or makes for a better presentation).

Comment: I've also read that lists give some small unclear SEO boost as well, so yeah I guess it's a tie and the user wins.